# Interrogative questions beginning with "Which"

Tags: questions, interrogatives

In my grammar textbook, it is just written that in order to change a sentence to a question, we have to swap the places of subject and verb:

> *John has arrived.*
>
> *Has John arrived?*

But some questions need extra words to be completed. For example:

> *John has come from school.*
>
> *Where has John come from?*

Unfortunately there is nothing about the rules, if there is any, which govern the use and the place of these extra words. For example:

> *Which of the above statements is correct?*

OR

> *Which is of the above statements correct?*

Of course, the first sounds more natural to me than the second one, but I do not know any grammar rule which explicitly eliminates the second one. Why is the second question wrong? Is there any rule for forming questions other than the one I mentioned?

Comment: At least use the third person singular: John has, not have. Please fix  your question with the proper verb.

Comment: No extra words are needed in example #2.  The question that is asked by changing verb order is, *Has John come from school?*  Yes or No?  No, John has come from work.  Example #3 should be, *The above statement is correct.* with its question being, *Is the above statement correct?*  You're mixing things up a bit.  The question you are able to ask by switching verb order is limited in its scope.  I can't ask you the formula for table salt  by changing the word order in the sentence, *This is table salt.*

Comment: 'The above statements' is the group of things you are asking someone to select from, so the logical word order is _Which [one] of the above statements is correct?_  You say, correctly, that it sounds natural. There is no reason to put the verb _is_ in the middle.

Comment: The "default" question to be formed from *John has come from school* is *Has John come from school?,* following exactly the same principle as your first example. You only need a "wh-word" *(**which, where, why, what,...**)* if the thing you're asking about is something more complicated than *asking whether a straightforward **Subject + Verb [+ object]** assertion is true or not.*

Comment: ***Which is of the above statements correct**?* and ***Which is correct of the above statements**?* are both "syntactically valid" - but they're relatively unusual / literary / poetic "inversions" that would usually be considered non-idiomatic in most contexts.

Comment: In a partitive noun phrase  construction like "which of the above statements", the head ("which") can't be separated from its complement, i.e. the PP "of the above statements", by a verb. Thus, *"Which is of the above statements correct?" is ungrammatical.

Comment: @BillJ: In a context like *Although I read all the above statements in a book, I don't know which are true*, we don't *have* to "re-specify" the complement ***of the above statements / of them***. That's to say the two separate elements of the full construction don't always have to appear together, even if from some perspectives they have to be analysed as a single syntactic unit.

Comment: If the partitive PP complement is overtly expressed as complement of the head it can't be separated from it, especially by a verb. Which is why we can't say *"Which is of the above statements correct? That's what the OP is asking about. We can of course say "Which is correct", but that's a different construction.

Comment: Both of your sentences beginning with *which* are questions.  What are you asking?  Your question needs focus.

Answer (score 0):

We usually invert questions, unless the question word is the subject (or part of the subject).

So:

> You saw a cat?

> Who did you see? (inverted, because "Who" is not the subject - some speakers would use "whom" for that reason, but for many English speakers it has dropped out of use)

but

> Who saw a cat?  (not inverted, because "Who" is the subject.

In your example *Which of the above statements* is the subject, so it precedes the verb *is*.

Compare:

> Is one of the above statements correct?

which is a question without a question word, so the subject and verb are inverted.